# SWIG an SDK to Python

Tags: python, c++, g++, mingw, swig

I am a newbie in SWIG so I have absolutely no experience with it but I really want to use the SDK of a Riftek LASER (https://riftek.com/media/rit/SDK/RFDevice_SDK.zip).

The SDK itself contains some header files, dll and def files. I have written the following SWIG file until now:

```
/* rfdevice.i */
%module rfdevice
%{
#include <windows.i>
#include <typemaps.i>
#include "include/RF625Device.h"
#include "include/RF625Device_Legacy.h"
#include "include/RFDevice.h"
#include "include/RFEthernetDetector.h"
#include "include/RFEthernetDevice.h"
#include "include/RFQDPMotorDevice.h"
#include "include/RFSerialDevice.h"
#include "include/RFString.h"
#include "include/RFTypeDefs.h"
#include "include/serial.h"
%}
%include <windows.i>
%include <typemaps.i>

%apply void *INPUT {void *lpResultBuffer};
%apply float *OUTPUT {float *lpPointsBuffer};
%apply USHORT *OUTPUT {USHORT *lpCount};

%include "include/RFString.h"
%include "include/serial.h"
namespace RFDevice {
    %include "include/RFTypeDefs.h"
    %include "include/RFEthernetDetector.h"
    %include "include/RFDevice.h"
    %include "include/RFEthernetDevice.h"
    %include "include/RFQDPMotorDevice.h"
    %include "include/RFSerialDevice.h"
    %include "include/RF625Device_Legacy.h"
    %include "include/RF625Device.h"
}
```

I can produce the rfdevice_wrap.c file but I cannot compile it because I get a lot of undefined reference from the compiler.

My question would be:
- Do I have to include the dll or def files in the i file somehow?
- Is there maybe a faster/easier way to get the SDK working with Python?

I am using g++ to compile with MinGW under Windows 7 64 bit.

---

So far I managed to identify my real problem. I modified the question according to the current state.

There is the following function definition in one of the headers:

```
USHORT ConvertResultToPoints(void IN *lpResultBuffer, float OUT *lpPointsBuffer, USHORT OUT *lpCount, USHORT *lpMeasureCnt = NULL, USHORT *lpPacketCnt = NULL, BOOL bChecksumCheck = FALSE);
```

Here the "IN" and "OUT" is causing for the SWIG some truble. I keep getting the following compiler error:

```
include\RF625Device_Legacy.h(259): Error: Syntax error in input(3).
```

In the SWIG documentation under argument handling there is the possible solution for the problem. I already included it into the i file but I keep getting the compiler error.

Comment: You should include the error messages from the compiler / linker here, see [mcve]

Comment: Why are you compiling *.c files with g++?

Comment: there is no way to include dll/def file in the i (interface) file, but you must include them during compiling code

Comment: Thanks for your answer V-master.

Alexander: There are no *.c files included in the SDK. Only *.h files. As I took a look at the files the syntax looked like more similar to C++ than to C. Actually I got less compiler error with g++ than with gcc.

Comment: 1) Never include .i files using #include. It makes no sense, they are not C or C++ 2) SWIG does not recurse headers so header files must be included in the correct order. 3) Don't include .i files with a namespace. The syntax errors you get are most likely due to an unknown definition, e.g. the export declarations

Answer (score 0):

You can start out like this. I use CMake

This is my CMakeLists.txt file. I can create the RFString objects so far

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)

find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

set_source_files_properties(RFDevice_SDK.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)

set(DEPS_PREFIX ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/linux)

link_directories(${DEPS_PREFIX})

set(RFDEVICE_LIBS_NAMES RFDevice3)

foreach(lib ${RFDEVICE_LIBS_NAMES})
  find_library(
    ${lib}_LIB
    NAMES ${lib}
    PATHS ${DEPS_PREFIX}
    PATH_SUFFIXES i386 x86_64
  )
  set(RFDEVICE_LIBS ${RFDEVICE_LIBS} ${${lib}_LIB})
endforeach()

message(${RFDEVICE_LIBS})

set(swig_rfdevice_sdk_HEADERS
  ./include/linuxTypeDefs.h
  ./include/RFString.h
)

set(swig_rfdevice_sdk_SOURCES
)

swig_add_module(swig_rfdevice_sdk python RFDevice_SDK.i ${swig_rfdevice_sdk_HEADERS} ${swig_rfdevice_sdk_SOURCES})

swig_link_libraries(swig_rfdevice_sdk ${RFDEVICE_LIBS} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

Here is the .o file

```
%module(docstring="This is a Python wrapper for RFDevice3") swig_rfdevice_sdk
#pragma SWIG nowarn=320
%{

  #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
  // Try to ignore cast between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object
  #include "stdint.h"
  #include "linuxTypeDefs.h"
  #include "RFString.h"
%}

#ifdef _SWIG_WIN32
%include "windows.i"
#endif

%include "carrays.i"
%array_class(char, charArrayClass);
%array_functions(char, charArray);

// Individual modules
%include "linuxTypeDefs.h"
%include "RFString.h"
```

I had to install an old version glibc++ to make it work. Alternatively, you can link to an old version of glibc++.

Comment: Judging how the interface is created, I would use ctypes instead and create structures with the same binary layout in Python and simply call them.